# Programmatically access mp3 tags from a file that is currently playing in media player

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, media-player, media

My question is related to grabbing file information from different media players.
How can I access mp3 file tags of a file that is playing in media player like `winamp` or `aimp`. I need to implement something similar to `last.fm` `scrobller` but i really have no idea where to start. I'm using `.NET 4`.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, last.fm uses custom plugins to provide such service to the user. Basically, you write custom plugin for each type of multimedia player (winamp, aimp, etc.) that transfers "currently playing" data to the server. Plugins are usually written in C++.

If that's not an option, you could try accessing window using [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and find the playlist window (though that could prove bothersome).

To read tag data you'd need either custom or third-party tag reader. In C# I'd strongly recommend using [taglibsharp](http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/).

Comment: thanx for the response! i didn't know that it is special plugin for each media player. i thought it is something universal for all the types.